# Excel/CSV - putting a single quote to keep leading zeros does not work on a Mac

Tags: excel, macos, csv

Other suggested to keep the leading zeros in Excel/CSV, I can just add the single quote character. However, this does not work on a Mac properly. The single quote shows up, which is something that I do not want.

Please see image for more details.

[image]

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aae07b39-865f-4c68-a07f-7cad2dfd6733/how-do-i-open-csv-using-excel-without-deleting-leading-zeros?forum=isvvba

Comment: Try the following instead: `="00100"`

Comment: Use the file import wizard and, on Step 3, check the "Text" box (instead of General) for each column when you import.

Answer (score -1):

I can just use "=""00100""" to keep the leading zeros.

[image]